# how to make a string to be part of a code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

For example if I have

```
var x = "console";
```

is it possible to run

x.log("Hello"); 
in javascript?
I ran it using window and eval but it wasn't working or is there a specific way to use those?

Comment: `window[x].log('hello');` should indeed work

Comment: I recommend looking for an alternative to whatever problem you are trying to solve, so it doesn't involve evaluating arbitrary strings, it sounds neither safe nor performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways of using a string to call the original function for console.

```js
eval("console").log("hello world");

window["console"].log("hello world");
```

If the string is "log" here is how it would work.

```js
console["log"]("hello world");
```

If you only wanted to use strings you could do something like so:

```js
eval("console")["log"]("hello world");
window["console"]["log"]("hello world");
eval("console.log('hello world')");
```

Comment: ok. what if the string is "log" instead of "console"? would that still work?

Comment: in this case, you may have a look here: [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: @kemicofa Thank You so much!!! The code console["log"]("hello world"); worked for me. I was putting a dot after console this whole time.